Issue with rending table in Readme.md
I want to add a table in readme.md and I am using below code/lines but its not rendering properly
    | Relational | Non-Relational |
    |------------|----------------|
    | Standardized | Non-Standardized |
    | Vertically Scalable | Horizontally Scalable|
    | Fixed Schema | Dynamic Schema |
    | ACID | BASE |
    | Efficient and reliable to handle complex code | Simple and flexible to handle significant changes but inefficient to handle complex |

I am displaying like this- (pic attached)
Can someone please help?
As per my understanding it should render into a table?

Your table is in one line where it is supposed to be multiple lines which is causing it not to render properly. Below I corrected the table to not be in a single line.
| Relational | Non-Relational |
| ---------- | -------------- |
| Standardized | Non-Standardized |
| Vertically Scalable | Horizontally Scalable |
| Fixed Schema | Dynamic Schema |
| ACID | BASE |

Your final table should look like this:



Relational
Non-Relational




Standardized
Non-Standardized


Vertically Scalable
Horizontally Scalable


Fixed Schema
Dynamic Schema


ACID
BASE



If you would like to learn more about Markdown Tables, I would suggest you check out the Markdown Guide for Tables. In summary:

To add a table, use three or more hyphens (---) to create each column’s header, and use pipes (|) to separate each column. For compatibility, you should also add a pipe on either end of the row.
| Syntax      | Description |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| Header      | Title       |
| Paragraph   | Text        |


You can read the rest of the guide if you would like to know more like alignment or text formatting in tables.

How to know if its a single line or multi lines? Coz it looks like multi line in my Readme.md
Also, I copied your corrected table in my Readme and without saving when I do Preview it still shows the same (without rendering

So I found out the reason. My table was indented because it was a part of a section. But after de-indenting it's working fine.
Thank you
